# Why does this JavaScript not work in my SSR Report

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report and want to have a hyper link on my text box to open a web page.

This works for me ="http://devtrafficcomplaints/Complaint?CompId="+CStr(Fields!ComplaintID.Value)
but it opens in the same window.  I want to open in a new window.

I tried the JavaScript shown below, but it does not work, the report opens and the cell shows the icon indication it is a hyper link, but nothing happens when I click.

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://devtrafficcomplaints/Complaint?CompId='+CStr(Fields!ComplaintID.Value)','_blank'))"
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the URL will contains exactly what is in between the double quotes so it will have the "Cstr(...." as part of the URL.

Try the following

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://devtrafficcomplaints/Complaint?CompId=" + CStr(Fields!ComplaintID.Value) + "','_blank'))"
```

You need to set the Action Property of the text box to be "Go to URL".

Note: *The actual Textbox content can be something entirely different from the URL if you want to hide the URL from the users - but one step at a time!*

[image]

Then set the Action expression to the expression I stated above.

**You must deploy the report**

The link will not work in Visual Studio's designer, the report needs to be deployed so you can view it in a browser before this link will work.

Comment: It's not a typo, the structure of the expression is wrong

Comment: Thank you for your response as well. However this did not work either

Comment: @Perry - I think this is just missing the single quote after the `CompId=`.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a few more things. I was concentrating on the expression being wrong but there might be a few things you have not done.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra single quote.

Corrected:

```
javascript:void(window.open('http://devtrafficcomplaints/Complaint?CompId='+CStr(Fields!ComplaintID.Value),'_blank'))
```